# Send files to server via FTPS protocol

Tags: java, android, ftps

I'm creating an app which generates a CSV file and some PDFs. I want my app to send those files to a server via FTPS protocol.

I'm using Apache Commons Net FTP library and it was perfectly working when I had "Require TLS session resumption on data connection when using PORT P" unchecked, but since I enabled it I can't send my files.
An error appeared :
`450 TLS session of data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection`.

After some researches on this site I have overriden `_prepareDataSocket_` in order to overcome this problem but now it just creates empty files on the server.

There is my overriden function :

```java
@Override
    protected void _prepareDataSocket_(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            // Control socket is SSL
            final SSLSession session = ((SSLSocket) _socket_).getSession();
            if (session.isValid()) {
                final SSLSessionContext context = session.getSessionContext();
                try {
                    final Field sessionHostPortCache = context.getClass().getDeclaredField("sessionHostPortCache");
                    sessionHostPortCache.setAccessible(true);
                    final Object cache = sessionHostPortCache.get(context);
                    final Method method = cache.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class);
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    method.invoke(cache, String
                            .format("%s:%s", socket.getInetAddress().getHostName(), String.valueOf(socket.getPort()))
                            .toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), session);
                    method.invoke(cache, String
                            .format("%s:%s", socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), String.valueOf(socket.getPort()))
                            .toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), session);
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    throw new IOException(e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IOException(e);
                }
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Invalid SSL Session");
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is what FileZilla Server displays:
[FileZilla Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzQWn.png)

Answer (score 0):

will this answer on another forum help?
http://forum.rebex.net/5673/450-error-connecting-to-ftp-requiring-explicit-ftp-over-tls

Comment: no it doesn't seem to work in java... at least I didn't find a way to modify ftp options like in this answer